# SQL - Get total certification count from people on a planet (3 separate tables)

Tags: mysql, sql

I honestly have no idea how to approach this problem. I've gotten up to `SELECT name` and then I'm lost (kind of embarrassing).

The problem: Find the number of certifications held by people grouped by planet. This should have two columns the first, "name" will be the names of planets that have at least one certification. The second column should be "CertCount" and will be the number of certifications held by people from that planet for example if Lee is certified in "Viper" and "Mechanic" and Kara is certified in "Viper" and they are both from Caprica, then the "CertCount" for caprica should be 3:

```
CREATE TABLE `bsg_cert` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `bsg_cert_people` (
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`,`pid`),
  KEY `pid` (`pid`),
  CONSTRAINT `bsg_cert_people_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cid`) REFERENCES `bsg_cert` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `bsg_cert_people_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`pid`) REFERENCES `bsg_people` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `bsg_people` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `homeworld` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `homeworld` (`homeworld`),
  CONSTRAINT `bsg_people_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`homeworld`) REFERENCES `bsg_planets` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `bsg_planets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `population` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `capital` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Answer (score 1):

Joining them all up doing a count with a group by should do the trick:

```
SELECT  planet.name ,
    COUNT(*) AS cert_count
FROM    bsg_cert_people people_cert
    JOIN bsg_people people ON people.id = people_cert.pid
    JOIN bsg_planet planet ON people.homeworld = planet.id
GROUP BY planet.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pl.name, count(cert) AS "CertCount"
FROM bsg_planets pl
JOIN bsg_people pe ON pl.id = pe.homeworld
JOIN bsg_cert_people cp ON cp.pid = pe.id
GROUP BY pl.id
```

I think this is it.